# At the moment I'm on 1.6 I have downloaded 1.7.8.8. Is there any way I can transfer from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: paypal, prestashop

At the moment I'm on 1.6 I have downloaded 1.7.8.8.

I have problems with it and it won't let me get into modules + my payment (payPal) is not working.
Is there any way I can transfer from 1.6 to 1.7 but not the problems I'm having
just the stock mainly and then sort it out from there.

I can't do anything as my Modules are not working

Comment: This appears to be a question for Prestashop support

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. Using a module may be a good idea if you're not experienced with migrating from one version to another.

I don't want to promote any particular solution, so I'll share with you a link to the module capable of migrating the data from one version to another:
https://addons.prestashop.com/en/search?search_query=migration

Most of the time, you install a module on the new version, you install a "bridge" on the old version, and then you can start transferring the data.